# Angular 5 Form Control Price Pattern Validation Always Returns Invalid

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I'm trying to require that a price be a number with 2 decimal places. No matter what number I enter the field is always invalid, any pointers would be appreciated!

HTML:

//What I use to test

```
Valid? {{ price.valid }}
```

```
<input 
    type="number" 
    step="0.01"
    name="price" 
    id="price" 
    required 
    placeholder="Enter Price"
    min="0" 
    formControlName="price"
>
```

TS:

```
let pricePattern = "/^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/";
this.name = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.price = new FormControl('', [
Validators.required,
Validators.pattern(pricePattern)
]);
```

Comment: I tried your pattern here: https://regexr.com/ and it seemed to work. Is it possible the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: Use `let pricePattern = /^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/;` or `"^\\d+\\.\\d{0,2}$"`

Comment: @DeborahK - I do not know, that is why I am asking. I just don't see what else it could be.